# how to apply ANOVA in testing the independence?

Tags: r, compare, anova, p-value

I would like to test the independence of a set of data, reproducible example as below:

```
income <- c("q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q1","q2","q3","q4","q5")
v1 <- as.numeric(round(runif(20,40,60),2))
v2 <- as.numeric(round(runif(20,10,20),2))
v3 <- as.numeric(round(runif(20,100,200),2))
v4 <- as.numeric(round(runif(20,0,20),2))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(income,v1,v2,v3,v4))

    income    v1    v2     v3    v4
1       q1 47.78  18.7 148.75 14.15
2       q2 59.22 19.95 141.65  2.63
3       q3 58.34 14.96 169.94    20
4       q4 40.35 12.28 143.82 12.14
5       q5 59.72 17.14 191.72 10.66
6       q1 59.44 10.32 128.23     1
7       q2 47.65 13.87 187.51  5.74
...
```

I want to test the independence of v1,v2,v3 and v4 between different income groups (q1-q5)

it should be like

```
income     v1           v2          v3          v4        p-value
  q1    mean.v1.q1  mean.v2.q1  mean.v3.q1  mean.v4.q1
  q2    mean.v1.q2  mean.v2.q2  mean.v3.q2  mean.v4.q2
  q3    mean.v1.q3  mean.v2.q3  mean.v3.q3  mean.v4.q3
  q4    mean.v1.q4  mean.v2.q4  mean.v3.q4  mean.v4.q4
  q5    mean.v1.q5  mean.v2.q5  mean.v3.q5  mean.v4.q5
```

I think I should apply ANOVA to achieve the test result, but I am not sure how.
Can anyone help?

I came up with the below script, is this the correct way? anything to improve?
Thank you!

```
v1mean <- as.data.frame(tapply(v1,income,mean))
colnames(v1mean) <- "v1"
v2mean <-  as.data.frame(tapply(v2,income,mean))
colnames(v2mean) <- "v2"
v3mean <- as.data.frame(tapply(v3,income,mean))
colnames(v3mean) <- "v3"
v4mean <- as.data.frame(tapply(v4,income,mean))
colnames(v4mean) <- "v4"

mean <- cbind(income=rownames(v1mean),v1mean,v2mean,v3mean,v4mean)
library(reshape)
mean <- melt(mean,id="income")

aov <- aov(value~variable + income,data=mean)
summary(aov)
```

Comment: is this a question about how to program it in R or what ANOVA technique to use?  If the latter (I think so), then it belongs on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks. It is about how to program it in R.